# What is the exact meaning of "App in Focus" shown in Crashlytics ? And is it nearly accurate?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have seen the log in Crashlytics (In Fabric) that a specific crash has happened multiple times in the app.

But the issue report shows 3% for "App in focus" as shown in the image below,
[image]

I want to know,

- Whats the exact meaning of "App in focus" (In some places the meaning is "The percentage of times that the app was in focus when the crash occurred.")
- Here what the term focus means ? Does it mean (App in completely background or App is open but some other controls like notification centre or Control centre is shown on top of the app ?

Can anyone give a clear meaning of it ?

Comment: Thanks! These measure wether or not the app is in the background or not when not. It uses simple logic of the onresume method being called and onpause. Let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: @ToddBurner : Is there any official documentation kind of thing where its stated ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An in-focus app means an app that is in the foreground and actively being used by a user at the time of a crash.

This answer is from engineer in fabric.

Comment: Can you share the official link where its stated ?

Comment: There is not official link. I send a email to fabric's engineer.